# Why step up transformer is used at the generating station to step up the transmission line voltage?

Tags: transformer, mains, transmission-line

In generating stations step up transformers are used to reduce losses. why?

Comment: Resistive losses are \$ I^2*R \$. Higher voltage -> lower current -> lower losses.

Answer (score 2):

1. When a step up transformer raises the voltage of a given, fixed amount of power, according to Watt's Law the current must be divided by whatever the voltage is multiplied by in order to maintain the same total power (W=V*A).
2. With the increased voltage, you can drive more current through the same resistance-value of transmission line (ignoring heat-related resistance changes).
   -Better yet: You can drive the same current theough the same line, with the same *absolute* voltage drop, thus increasing efficiency because the voltage drop is now a smaller portion of the (higher) total voltage.
   -Even better: A higher voltage can push the same power through the transmission line at the associated lower current with less absolute voltage drop (due to pushing less current through the resistance) AND that already lower voltage drop is even lower compared to the (higher) total voltage, and this is even without figuring in the reduction of line resistance due to lower ohmic heating!

Comment: I'd add to the first part that: "Since transformers are passive components, they can't add any energy into the system." Thus Watt... etc.

Comment: @Dave Ok, I "Community Wiki'd" it & added those changes. Now anyone else can add their helpful insight(s) to it directly :-)

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB I deleted my comment. Others can do as they like.

Answer (score 0):

Transformers are constant power device. That means the power is constant through primary and secondary. While voltage is stepped up current becomes low as P= V*I and here P is constant. As current I becomes low, (I^2)*R losses become less. So in generating stations voltage is stepped up to reduce the losses.

Answer (score 0):

To decrease the current intensity passing in the wire and according to the relation p=I^2 R 
When the electric current intensity decrease the power decrease 
So by this way we have decreased the consumed power so there is no considerable loss in energy